# Why is BIC overfitting for a large data set but not from a smaller sample?

Tags: model-selection, model, nonlinear-regression, bic

I'm trying to use the BIC to select between two non-linear models. One model has 2 parameters, the other has 4. The models are based on rate equations for consecutive reactions, and have good support from other data.

I have several data sets, each of about 2000 points. Some intuitively look like the 4 parameter model, and fitting with this model agrees well with the other data. Others give unrealistic parameter estimates with the 4 parameter model, and look very overfitted.

Using the BIC to distinguish the models for a dataset always results in the choice of the more complex model. However, taking a random sample of 500 points and using the same code prefers what looks like the correct choice. I can understand (I think) why reducing the number of points would favour the simpler model, but I struggle to understand why such a dramatic difference occurs between ~2000 and 500.

[image: An example]

In these examples, the left side shows an example I feel to be overfitted with the more complex function, and the right shows one I feel fits well to the complex model. I am happy to provide supporting information.

EDIT: From reading Burnham and Anderson's "Model selection and multimodel inference" section 2.3 I suspect my problem has something to do with the large set being poorly explained by the relatively simple model and that the Takeuchi Information Criterion may be more suitable

Comment: The penalty for 2000 points is ln(2000) = ~7.6 x k, while 500 is ln(500) = ~6.21 x k (which doesn't seem to be too large of a difference). So if the addition of more parameters is leading to a very small gain in log likelihood, then it's feasible that either dataset is selecting a smaller model.